# Python subprocess.Popen in other directory

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have this command:

```
grep = subprocess.Popen('head -20'.split(), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ls = subprocess.Popen('ls'.split(), stdout=grep.stdin)
output_lines = grep.communicate()[0]
```

How can I run this command in other directory? For example in /home/?

Comment: unrelated: you could use `os.listdir('/home')[:20]` instead of running `cd /home; ls | head -20`. If the directory may contain potentially large number of entries; you could use `itertools.islice(os.scandir('/home'), 20)` instead (it should work even if there are millions of files in the directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid changing the global process working directory with `os.chdir()` (that you don't want if your program uses multiple threads), you could pass `cwd='/home'` parameter to `Popen()`.

Comment: Did not know that it has a cwd parameter. Helped a lot not dealing with changing cwd.

Answer (score 1):

The subprocess will inherits the python processes current working directory.
Just change the directory before calling Popen. For example:

```
import os

old_dir = os.getcwd()
os.chdir( '/home' )
grep = subprocess.Popen( ... )
os.chdir( old_dir )
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help),it will be useful to put  your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

With `chdir`:

```
import os

os.getcwd()
>> 'a/sample/path'

os.chdir('/home/')

os.getcwd()
>> '/home/'
```